# Print which word comes first alphabetically and check if certain character exist in a string?

Tags: java, if-statement, char, alphabetical

How can I print which word comes first (alphabetically) when I prompts the user to write two words? and how to check if a certain character exist in that scanned words?

For ex: if the user wrote "Word" and "Apple" how can I print these two words in alphabetical order. Also, I wrote a program to check if char 'z' appears on either words or not, but I don't know what's wrong about it? Here is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Pr7{
  public static void main(String[] args){

    //print two words and read them..

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);    
    String Word1;
    String Word2;

    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("* Please write one word: ");
       Word1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("* Please write one word: ");
       Word2 = scan.nextLine();

    //Prints which word has more characters in it..

    if (Word1.length() > Word2.length())
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word1 + ")" + " has more characters.");

    else if (Word2.length() > Word1.length())
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word2 + ")" + " has more characters.");
    else
       System.out.println("- " + "(" + Word1 + ")" + " has equal characters with " + "(" + Word2 + ")");

    //Prints which word comes first (alphabetically).. *** WORNG ***

    char ch;
    int compare = Word1.compareTO(Word2);

    if (compare < 0)  
       System.out.print(compare)
    else   
      if (compare > 0)
    a is larger 
   }else  
   {  

   //Prints whether the letter 'z' appears in either word.. *** WRONG ***

   if (Word1 = 'z')
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' appears in the first word.");
   else if (Word2 = 'z')
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' appears in the second word.");
   else
     System.out.print("- Letter 'z' doesn't appears in either word.");

  }//main
}//Pr7
```

the last two operators are wrong and I need the right way to fix it.

Comment: `Word1 = 'z'` ... You should think about that and why it not do, what you think it does.

Comment: @Tom Indeed. That shouldn't even compile and the error would explain exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @Tom I wanted to write a Boolean statement that indicates if 'z' appears in "Word1" (which is the word that the user entered) or not. I thought about it a lot.

Comment: @Bader And how are comparisons made in Java (especially with Objects/Strings)? Hint: not with `=`. And even if you find the answer, that doesn't work here. You want to check if `z` is one of the characters in the String `Word1` and not if `Word1` is only a single `z`.

Comment: @Bader What you've done there is an *assignment* rather than an equality check. Equality checks use `==` not `=`. Regardless, that isn't the correct way to test if a string contains a particular char - I've explained how to do that in my answer. Please ensure when you copy/paste code into your questions that it *compiles*. Your code is missing semi-colons and has free text appearing in the code (`a is larger`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort two words, use [`String.compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-). You may find it easier to add them to a list, then sort that list using [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-). Strings are naturally sorted using alphabetical ordering.

To see if a string contains a specific character, use [`String.indexOf('z')`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) and test whether the return value is `-1`, which would indicate no match. Alternatively, as Tom suggests, you can use `String.contains("z")`, which requires you pass a string `"z"` rather than a char `'z'`.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand if you apply the changes on my program, so I know what I made wrong.

Comment: @Bader Yes, that would be easier for you. But you'll learn a lot more about the language if you use my hints and solve it yourself.

Comment: Duncan, you could also include the method `String.contains()` as a possible way check if `z` is part of the string.

Comment: your hints is useful and I knew about it before I ask these questions, but the thing is I don't know how to use it properly inside my program. Because, I have never used it before. So, are you going to help or just play games with me.

Comment: @Bader Can you explain what you don't understand? Your code example in your question doesn't include `String.indexOf()` or `String.contains()`, as Tom suggests. So it doesn't seem like you have tried to use my advice. Regarding "playing games with me", I expect a certain amount of effort on the part of the question asker. I won't spoon feed you code, particularly when it appears you're trying to learn the language.

Comment: @Duncan sorry I just had an overflow error. I've been working on that program, that prints barley 7 lines only, since a very long time. So, I reached the point to not put any more effort "on the part of the question asker". However, I appreciate your advises and I will try to figure it out, then I will put some feedback in-case of facing troubles with it. thank you

Comment: @Duncan you said when using String.indexOf() if it doesn't match a value of -1 will be return. but, what if it matched what would be returned ?

Answer (score 0):

this is how I fixed it..

```js
import java.util.*;
public class Pr6{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);    
    String word1;
    String word2;
    String sentence1;
    String sentence2;
    
    System.out.print("* Please enter a word: ");
    word1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("* Please enetr a word: ");
    word2 = scan.nextLine();
    
    if (word1.length() > word2.length())
      System.out.print("The first word has more characters than the second word");
    else if (word1.length() < word2.length())
      System.out.print("The second word has more characters than the first word");
    else
      System.out.print("The characters in both words are equal");
    
    System.out.println();
    
    if (word1.toLowerCase().charAt(0) < word2.toLowerCase().charAt(0))
      System.out.println(word1 + " (comes first alphabetically)");
    else if (word1.toLowerCase().charAt(0) > word2.toLowerCase().charAt(0))
      System.out.println(word2 + " (comes first alphabetically)");
    
    if (word1.toLowerCase().indexOf('z') >= 0)
      System.out.println("Letter 'z' appears in the first word.");
    else
      System.out.println("Letter 'z' doesn't appear in the first word.");
    if (word2.toLowerCase().indexOf('z') >= 0)
      System.out.println("Letter 'z' appears in the second word.");
    else
      System.out.println("Letter 'z' doesn't appear in the second word.");
    
    System.out.print("* Please enter a sentence: ");
    sentence1 = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("* Please enter a sentence: ");
    sentence2 = scan.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("The first sentence has " + sentence1.length() + " characters");
    System.out.println("The second sentence has " + sentence2.length() + " characters");
    
    if (sentence1.toLowerCase().indexOf(" the ") >= 0)
      System.out.println("Substring 'the' appears in the first sentence.");
    else
      System.out.println("Substring 'the' doesn't appear in the first sentence.");
    if (sentence2.toLowerCase().indexOf(" the ") >= 0)
      System.out.println("Substring 'the' appears in the second sentence.");
    else
      System.out.println("Substring 'the' doesn't appear in the second sentence.");
    
    if (sentence1.length() >= 11)
      System.out.println(sentence1.replace(sentence1.substring(8, 10), "the"));
    if (sentence2.length() >= 11)
      System.out.println(sentence2.replace(sentence2.substring(8, 10), "the"));
      
  }//main
}//Pr6
```